# Rank() with Null first in Bigquery based on multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

I have a data like as shown below

```
Subject_id T1  T2  T3  T4  T5
1234
1234       21  22  23  24  25
3456       34  31    
3456       34  31  36  37  39
5678       65  64  62  61  67
5678       65  64  62      67
9876       12  13  14  15  16
4790       47  87  52  13  16
```

As you can see above, subject_ids `1234`,`3456` and `5678` are repeating.

I would like to remove those repeating subjects when they have `null/empty/blank` value in any of the columns like `T1,T2,T3,T4`,`T5`.

Now the problem is in real time, I have more than 250 columns and not sure whether I can put 250 where clause checking for `null` value. So, I was trying with row_number(), rank(). Not sure which one is better. The below is what I was trying

```
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY subject_id,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5) NULLS FIRST
from table A;
```

But it throws syntax error `Syntax error: Unexpected keyword NULLS at [1:62]`

I expect my output to be like below

```
Subject_id T1  T2  T3  T4  T5
1234       21  22  23  24  25   
3456       34  31  36  37  39
5678       65  64  62  61  67
9876       12  13  14  15  16
4790       47  87  52  13  16
```

As you can see, the output doesn't contain rows which had at least 1 null/empty/blank value in `T1,T2,T3,T4,T5` columns.

Can help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
WHERE NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(FORMAT('%t', t), r'NULL')
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row Subject_id  t1  t2  t3  t4  t5   
1   1234        21  22  23  24  25   
2   3456        34  31  36  37  39   
3   5678        65  64  62  61  67   
4   9876        12  13  14  15  16   
5   4790        47  87  52  13  16
```

Comment: Hi @Mikhail Berlyant - As you have answered most of questions related to google bigquery in SO, Can I check with you on recommendations for google bigquery tutorial that provides a sample dataset and allows us to experiment most of the google query syntax etc. I would like to master Bigquery. But looking for a resource which can direct someone like me.  Did you author any book on bigquery?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY subject_id
                          ORDER BY (T1 IS NULL OR T2 IS NULL OR T3 IS NULL OR T4 IS NULL OR T5 IS NULL) DESC
                         )
FROM table A;
```

I might approach this problem differently, but this appears to be what you are trying to write.

Comment: I want to check that Null/blank/empty value for more than 250 columns as mentioned in question. So do I have to type in all those 250 column names?

Comment: @TheGreat . . . You can query the metadata tables and construct the query in BigQuery or in a spreadsheet.